# Is there a difference between ISH and ISHH? (In Situ Hybridization, In Situ Hybridization Histochemistry)

Tags: molecular-genetics, terminology, methods

I came across the term **ISHH** in my document and discovered that it stands for *In Situ Hybridization Histochemistry*. I's translating to Russian a document that uses this abbreviation.

[Example](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1257393/) from the PubMed:

> We then validated these findings by using a combination of tools, including the analysis of an additional brain region in an independent subject cohort, cross-validation with an alternate custom microarray platform, and follow-up with in situ hybridization histochemistry (ISHH).

Is there any difference between ISH and ISHH, or are these just synonyms for the same method, [in situ hybridization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In_situ_hybridization)?

Comment: Helpful histochemistry def'n: "the branch of science concerned with the identification and distribution of the chemical constituents of tissues by means of stains, indicators, and microscopy."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The term appears to be in use as a synonym.  PLOS ONE is a good journal, and in it [Okubo, 2016](https://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0153375) write "The protocol for ISHH was described in detail previously [22]."  Where [22] is [Yamanaka, 2007](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1891330/), describing a classic ISH protocol.

Note that *both* papers use good old fashioned nuclear tract emulsion for S-35 labelled probes.  The ISHH protocol is in its own section separate from IHC.  It seems a bit odd because no literal "chemistry" is involved in recognizing the target - the RNA probe binds non-covalently and emits radiation.  However, as noted in the question discussion, IHC is formally defined ([OED](https://www.lexico.com/definition/histochemistry)) as "the branch of science concerned with the identification and distribution of the chemical constituents of tissues by means of stains, indicators, and microscopy".  For example, though I have seen immunofluorescence and immunohistochemistry used to describe mutually exclusive visualization options, noncovalent binding of fluorophore-labelled antibodies is [described](https://www.jacksonimmuno.com/technical/products/applications/immunohistochemistry-immunofluorescence) as "fluorescent IHC".